# Can I clipPath on a div in Vercel/OG Image generator in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, vercel

Basically I am trying to display a div which splits a text section from a image via a clipPath which is a inverted triangle. (The parent Element is a flex row) I tested it in normal React and everything seemed to work, now as I copied the working code to the `og.tsx`, it somehow just displays a square as you can see in the image:

**The result should look like this**:

[image]

**Instead it looks like this:**

[image]

The code i used for clipping the div is the following:

```
...
<div
  style={{
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  width: '132px',
  height: '100%',
  clipPath: 'polygon(100% 0, 0% 100%, 0 0)',
  }}
 />
```

Comment: It didn't resolve the question, but i found a work arround... Just convert the Polygon to a SVG ^^ I guess the parser of Vercel/Satori just doesn't work by now [Github Issue](https://github.com/vercel/satori/issues/206)